# How to properly stub a Rails association methods via mocha and test/unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mocha.js

I'm working on an app where most, if not all, of the data is scoped to a `current_organization`. So in my find calls in my controllers, I have things like this for example:

```
def show
  @user = current_organization.users.find(params[:id])
end
```

However, in my controller tests, I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper way (or any way) to stub these calls so that I can test things like:

```
get :show, :id => 1
assert_response :success
```

Those are failing saying "AR can't find user with ID=1 and organization_id = 3" or whatever. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get around it.

My setup block looks something like this:

```
setup do
  company = organizations(:company) # fixture
  @controller.stubs(:current_organization).returns(company)
  # now what do I stub, if anything?
end
```

I tried doing stuff like: `company.stubs(:users).returns([users(:one), users(:two)])` but that doesn't work because the AR `find()` call doesn't exist for a basic array.

Should I set the fake users array to be a variable like `fake_users` and then do something like `fake_users.stubs(:find).returns(@user)`? That didn't feel right, but maybe that's the proper way.

I'm just looking for the best way to handle this. I'm using mocha and test/unit, if that matters or helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you specifically need access to the `fake_users`, I think the simplest thing you could do is probably something like this :-

```
company.stubs(:users => stub('users', :find => users(:one)))
```

Unfortunately, this kind of code is awkward to mock. You will notice that my suggested solution is rather brittle.